# Van Westendorp price modeling in R

Tags: r, modeling

I want to do price modeling using the Van Westendorp price sensitivity meter.

Can anybody provide me resources describing how to do this using R?

Comment: I can't suggest anything regarding R, but, in case you use SPSS, there is the macro for PSM on my web page.

Comment: Conjoint, is by far a better method for identifying price sensitivity. But, I use this too when the client isn't willing to pay extra to have it done right. Keep in mind though, that this model hasn't changed since 1976. There are other options out there...

Comment: @ttnphns I'm interested in that macro but couldn't find it on the web page.

Comment: Thanks ttnphns for helping me with SPSS. I'll surely try to use it.

Comment: @rolando, see "Cumulative curves" collection. If you get questions on that, don't hesitate to ask by email.

Comment: @ttnphns  Very kind of you!

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen, PSM and conjoint are indented for different purposes and should be used simultaneously. PSM is for price perception "as is" and gives "price as quality indicator" assessment that is not possible with conjoint. Conjoint is for price elasticity. Conjoint assumes that quality doesn't change over course of an experiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there's a nicer way, but here's an example. Obviously, you'll have to make sure your data is clean ie, no bogus elements where notexpensive > tooexpensive, etc. Survey respondents have a knack for messing up this question. I used `Hmisc` here because it allows you to easily invert with `Ecdf(...,what="1-F")`.

From your own data, you'd replace my `sample()` calls in the initial `data.frame()`, below, with the relevant columns from your survey.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(
"toocheap"=sample(1:15,1000,replace=T),
"notbargain"=sample(5:25,1000,replace=T),
"notexpensive"=sample(10:35,1000,replace=T),
"tooexpensive"=sample(20:45,1000,replace=T)
)
a <- Ecdf(dat$toocheap,what="1-F",pl=F)$y[-1]
b <- Ecdf(dat$notbargain, pl=F)$y[-1]
c <- Ecdf(dat$notexpensive,what = "1-F", pl=F)$y[-1]
d <- Ecdf(dat$tooexpensive,pl=F)$y[-1]

ecdf1 <- data.frame("variable"=c("toocheap"),"ecdf" = a, "value"=as.numeric(names(a)))
ecdf2 <- data.frame("variable"=c("notbargain"), "ecdf" = b, "value"=as.numeric(names(b)))
ecdf3 <- data.frame("variable"=c("notexpensive"),"ecdf" = c, "value"=as.numeric(names(c)))
ecdf4 <- data.frame("variable"=c("tooexpensive"),"ecdf" = d, "value"=as.numeric(names(d)))

dat2 <- rbind(ecdf1,ecdf2,ecdf3,ecdf4)

dat <- melt(dat)
dat <- merge(dat,dat2,by=c("variable","value"))

ggplot(dat, aes(value, ecdf, color=variable)) + 
geom_step() + 
scale_y_continuous("",formatter="percent") + 
labs(x="Price in $")
```

[image: Van Westendrop Price Modelling in R]

Comment: The complete Van Westendorp PSM study implies more plots than the one shown here.

Comment: @ttnphns, My understanding was that the OP just wanted to know how to get the PSM output.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brandon. You are a great help.  I was not getting any resources regarding Van Westendorp.

Comment: Truthfully, this is the only point of interest. The intersection of the lines above represent lower and upper bound of price, intersection of notexpensive * notbargain = optimal price.

Answer (score 2):

I am developing this library: https://github.com/kintero/psmr

```
# library(devtools)
# devtools::install_github("kintero/psmr")
library(psmr)

set.seed(455)
dat <- data.frame(
  "toocheap"=rpois(400, 4)+runif(50, 0, 1)
)
dat$cheap<-dat$toocheap+runif(50, 1, 2)
dat$expensive<-dat$cheap+runif(50, 2, 4)
dat$tooexpensive<-dat$expensive+runif(50, 3, 4)

psmObject<-psm(dat, "toocheap", "cheap", "expensive", "tooexpensive")
plot(psmObject)
```

[image]

It's easy to use and only has 3 functions.